# opencv single h264 raw frame as a binary string

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, h.264, mat

have created a rtsp client in python that receives a h264 stream and returns single h264 raw frames as a binary strings. I am trying to process each h264 frames on-the-fly.

I have unsuccessfully tried several ways to convert this frame into a numpy array for processing.

So far I know that cv2.VideoCapture only accepts a file name as it argument, not a frame neither a StringIO object (file like pointer to a buffer), but I need to pass to it my string.

I have also tried something like:

```
nparr = np.fromstring(frame_bin_str, np.uint8)
img_np = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
```

tried diferent flags. but also failed miserably.

after many other failed attempts , I ran out of ideas.

To summarize what I need to do: I have a h264 raw frame in a variable and I need to create an openvc valid numpy array of it, or somehow end up with a VideoCapture object containing that single frame, so I can process the frame.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Hope this all makes sense.

Thank you in advance

Comment: afaik openCV doesn't support h264 raw format. In our current project someone wrote some code which reads those files frame by frame (jumping to byte positions for a given frame number) and interpretes byte information manually to get openCV usable data according to h264 format rules.

Comment: Thank you for your response Micka. If I dump the frames into a file with a "\x0\x00\x00\x001" separator. and I create a VideoCapture object from it. all works just perfect. I can read and retrieve frame by frame and manipulate them fine. So I assumed the support was there. I can't figure how to load a single frame rather than a file.

Comment: did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As Micka suggested, there is no support for h264 RAW format in OpenCV and we should convert it ourselves.

I think you should be reshaping the `nparr` to the shape of the incoming image. Not necessary to do imdecode. Use imshow to display the result and verify.

Here is the code I used to convert a 16 bit RAW image (grayscale) in a similar way. I have renormalized my image before displaying.

```
framenp = np.fromstring(framestr, dtype=np.uint16).reshape((1024,1280))
#renormalizing to float
framenp = (framenp*1./framenp.max())
framenp.dtype = np.float
cv2.imshow('frame', cv2.resize(framenp, (640,480)))
```