# Counting the Number of Frames in a Video file using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to count total number of Frames in my video file ('foo.h264').

```
>>> import numpy as nm
>>> import cv2
>>> cap = cv2.VideoCapture('foo.h264')
>>> cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT' is not defined
>>> cap.get(5)
25.0
>>> cap.get(7)
-192153584101141.0
```

So I think `get(5)` is giving frame rate and `get(7)` gives total number of frames. Obviously `get(7)` is incorrect in the above case. So to verify I tried to find these values in an `.avi` file.

```
>>> cap = cv2.VideoCapture('foo.avi')
>>> cap.get(5)
29.97002997002997
>>> cap.get(7)
256379.0
```

I can calculate the total number of frames by multiplying `FPS` by duration of the video, but I'm not sure if the FPS given for `.h264` is right or not. Why does it give negative number of total frames? Is this a bug?

P.S: I recorded this video file (`.h264`) using raspberry pi camera.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25359288/1643946 (for avi containers)

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is using [imageio](https://imageio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which works for *some* videos.

```
import imageio
filename="person15_walking_d1_uncomp.avi"
vid = imageio.get_reader(filename,  'ffmpeg')
# number of frames in video
num_frames=vid._meta['nframes']
```

Comment: a more consistent solution is to use `meta_data = vid.get_meta_data();
num_frames = meta_data['nframes']`

Comment: When I try this, the result `num_frames` is `inf`. Surely that's wrong?

Comment: The duration is `5.03` and the fps is `30`. Can I just multiply these two quantities together? Probably not because the product is not an integer.

Comment: `num_frames = vid.count_frames()` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me (no opencv used):

```py
import imageio

file="video.mp4" #the path of the video
vid=imageio.get_reader(file,  'ffmpeg')
totalframes = vid.count_frames()

print(totalframes)
```

It will return the total frames :)

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out OpenCV does not support h.264 format ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161059/opencv-single-h264-raw-frame-as-a-binary-string/)). However, the documentation on Video Capture at [Python OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html/) mentions an integer argument for the get command. So, you're right on that count on using 5 and 7 instead of 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT'. You could try changing the capture format on the raspberry pi to avi.

Comment: Yes .h264 is just NAL stream and doesn't contain the information about the framerate. Now when I wrap the video in a container like .mp4 I am able to calculate the total number of frames. But the framerate of the new video is 25fps which is wrong. But from total number of frames and duration I can calculate the real framerate.